# ValueError: cannot compute LDA over an empty collection (no terms)

Tags: python, gensim, lda, topic-modeling

Getting this error in python when trying to compute lda for a smaller size of corpus but works fine in other cases.

The size of corpus is 15 and I tried setting the number of topic to 5 then reduced it to 2 but it still gives the same error : **ValueError: cannot compute LDA over an empty collection (no terms)**

getting error at this line :     `lda = models.LdaModel(corpus, num_topics=topic_number, id2word=dictionary, passes=passes)`

where corpus is `corpus = [dictionary.doc2bow(text) for a, id, text, s_date, e_date, qd, qd_perc in texts]`

Why is it giving no terms?

Comment: can you provide some sample input?

Comment: which part u need to see?

Comment: the corpus that you are passing... the input text

Comment: The corpus would be dict mappings .. right.? If I print corpus : [[(16, 1), (23, 1), (24, 1), (32, 1), (33, 1), (38, 3), (42, 2), (43, 1), (52, 1)], [(51, 1)], [], [(47, 1)], .... something like this.  Is the error because of the empty lists in between ( [] ) ?   The input text is list of tuples where I just retrieve the text part and pass it: `temp = []   for a,id,text,s_date,e_date,qd,qd_perc in texts: temp.append(text) ` after this `dictionary=corpora.Dictionary(temp)`

Comment: Did you do stopword removal?

Comment: try doing it without those empty lists and check...  I have a hunch that might be the reason

Comment: Removed stop_words. Let me try removing [ ] . But why it has empty lists? I am adding to dictionary as well.

Comment: @VivekKalyanarangan I did this `print("before", corpus, " \n len  ", len(corpus))
    corpus = [item for item in corpus if len(item) > 0]
    print("After", corpus, " \n len ", len(corpus))` and this in case of error : `before [[], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], []]  
 len   14
After []  
 len  0`  Why the corpus is empty?? dictionary is there.

Comment: Ok. So the reason why list of empty lists was coming up is `dictionary.filter_extremes(no_below=2, no_above=0.1)` I removed this and not getting any error now. The no_below and no_above parameter's value must be set carefully.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Finally figured it out. The issue with small documents is that if you try to filter the extremes from dictionary, you might end up with empty lists in corpus.`corpus = [dictionary.doc2bow(text)]`.

So the values of parameters in `dictionary.filter_extremes(no_below=2, no_above=0.1)` needs to be selected accordingly and carefully before `corpus = [dictionary.doc2bow(text)]`

I just removed the filter extremes and lda model runs fine now. Though I will change the parameter values in filter extreme and use it later.